# Spring EL not loading SystemProperties

Tags: java, spring, properties, el

I am using below configuration in context xml file to load properties in Java code, but i am getting just property name instead of value. when i run my app server and tries to access sytem properties using below way, it doesn't work. but if i use System.getProperty('') then it works. I dont know what i am missing.

```
<bean id="bean1" parent="parentBean">
     <property name="beanDao" ref="beanDao"/>  
    <property name="outputLocation"  value= "#{systemProperties['PRO1.LOCN']}"/>

</bean>
```

Java file:

```
@Override
public String getOutputLocation() throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return outputLocation;
}
 * @param outputLocation
 *            the outputLocation to set
 */
public void setOutputLocation(String outputLocation) {
    this.outputLocation = outputLocation;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you could use @Value annotation, why don't you specify the class for the bean? Check: http://kodejava.org/how-do-i-read-system-environment-variables-in-spring-el/

Comment: No, these two properties are defined in Parent class. I also looked at that but it doesn't work also i dont want to use annotations.